# migrate import when change package name in flutter

Tags: flutter, import, flutter-layout

I had

```
import 'package:nhg/share/ui/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:nhg/share/ui/theme/theme_app.dart';
```

when I change package name in pubspec.yaml and apply its. All **import**  don't automation update, Android Studio show error and I must manualy update it.

if when I import, I using style

```
import '../../../theme/theme_app.dart';
```

then it unaffect, but when I want to move file to other package, I will not exactly (don't automation update **import** ).

Who can hepl me, How to automation update when I change package name?

Comment: if you are using android studio you can use ctrl + shift + r and you can replace all package:nhg to package:whateveryouwant